# Svelte-kit and NPM module with Svelte src

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have an npm package, written in typescript, that also exports some svelte components, obviously svelte-kit will need the component src, and not a compiled component, I have explicitly added the location of this package to the svelte-kit `tsconfig.json` but I'm still hitting `Cannot use import outside a module:.... import App from "./components/App.svelte"`; (the `import App...` is a line of code within the the module src)

Can anybody advise what I need to do / setup in the npm package.json / build / typescript, and on the svelte-kit app that wants to consume this package?

The way I see it, I want this npm package to be consumed entirely from its typescript src, and get compiled / bundled with the rest of the app but not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use SvelteKit for the package project as well and it will handle the setup for you:

> Usually, you think of SvelteKit as an application framework, where the contents of the `src/routes` folder become the public pages of your application, and the `src/lib` folder is for shared code, i.e. an internal library. But you can use `svelte-kit package` to reverse this paradigm: your `src/lib` folder becomes the public facing package and the `src/routes` could be used for testing, as a demo and for documentation. We can also configure the packages entry point (or package root) using a `src/lib/index.js` file and SvelteKit even creates TypeScript definitions inside `.d.ts` files for you!  [You can read more about packaging libraries with SvelteKit in the Docs.](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging)

Quick Start Instructions:

- run `npm init svelte@next my-toast-lib-name`
- create `.js`, `.ts` or `.svelte` files inside `src/lib`
- (optionally) create an `src/lib/index.ts` file to re-export your files for easier importing
- run `npm install -D typescript svelte2tsx` to install necessary modules for packaging
- run `npm run package` to package up your library
- publish package to npm